# What are the guidelines for writing good questions (and titles)?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

It seems like a few of my questions have had their titles edited, either to add in capitalization, or to take it out (I've not yet seen both on the *same* question, though ;). I'm not sure if my title should be "Is There a Style Guide for Questions?" or "Is there a style guide for questions?", though I am now tending towards the latter (see above). (to get the wise-guy badge, you should edit the title of *this* question.)

Is there a general style guide for questions? Or are there side-by-side good Q/bad Q examples, either here or on meta? Things like: how to make your question specific, suggested limits on paragraph size, etc, etc.

Comment: I would also favor the second one; I must admit I edit questions from time to time (title or tags), but I'm not looking at any additional badges :)

Comment: Now, can I have my 'wise-guy' badge? :-)

Comment: I have added a set of 'guidelines'. Please upvote/downvote as appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ask a "good" question on CrossValidated?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated)

Answer (score 10):

Question title should follow sentence capitalization.

Exceptions to the above rule:

1. A proper noun in the question title/text should be capitalized.
2. ...

Comment: So-Called Title Case Reminiscent of Certain US Print Publications, Looks Anachronistic in New Media

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case#Headings_and_publication_titles

Comment: Proper noun capitalization isn't an exception.

Comment: @walkytalky I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @Srikant Sorry, I wasn't trying to be cryptic or anything. Just noting that you have a list of "exceptions", but the only one suggested so far isn't an exception at all, since sentence case already implies proper noun capitalization. "Proper nouns should *not* be capitalized" would be exceptional (and odd). I'm not sure we need any exceptions at all, though it's sensible to leave open the possibility.

Comment: And just to clarify in case that sounds critical, I think you've done a great job on all of these :)

Comment: @walkytalky I was not annoyed with your comment. I simply did not understand it. Feel free to edit the text as appropriate. I was thinking that perhaps not everyone understands that sentence capitalization implies capitalize proper nouns.

Answer (score 10):

If appropriate, provide sample data / sample code / reproducible example (with simulated data) in the question text along with a brief description of your data/code.

Comment: @Skrikant or a reproducible example (with simulated data).

Answer (score 9):

Ideally, a question should be self-contained.

In other words, readers should not have to download anything or search for anything to understand your question. Please provide links using the editor's link functionality and provide images using the image functionality to make the question self-contained.

Answer (score 7):

If possible a question title should be an actual question.

Answer (score 7):

If appropriate, to the extent possible, use mathematical notation/equations in the question text to lend precision to your question. You can use Tex for mathematical notation/equations.

Answer (score 6):

Provide details of what you already tried / your thoughts on the question so that appropriate answers can be given.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be specific to homework. Outline of what you've tried is helpful in real world cases too.

Comment: @walkytalky Agreed.

Answer (score 6):

Don't put a space before a closing bracket, comma, period or question/exclamation mark or after an opening bracket.

Comment: This is not fully on topic, but... I just hate it.

Comment: Me too :) (Everybody should browse some pages of the TeXbook :)

Comment: I agree with all of these, but spaces before commas in particular make my eyes bleed. There seems to have been a particular spate of people doing this sort of thing just lately, I am not sure where such a thing comes from.

Answer (score 4):

Don't add "e-mail flags" like [R], [newbie] or [svm] to your posts' titles. Use tags instead.

Answer (score 4):

It is best to be very sparing with details not needed to understand your question. Your question should stand on its own as a technical question. Lengthy personal details or personal pleas don't usually help and may even make your question less likely to be answered.

In particular be sparing with

- Salutations. Initial greetings are not needed.
- Personal details or history. A little detail can make your question vivid and you appear human, and that's fine, but your precise personal situation and/or knowledge of and/or ignorance of statistics need not be spelled out at length. It's fine to say that you are a learner or very new to some field, for example, and that can be said in one sentence.
- Closing comments on how much you would appreciate our help. We appreciate that you want to be polite and courteous, but your gratitude is taken as read. Wording such as "Thanks in advance" or "I would be very grateful for any help" is not needed and won't make us more likely to answer your question.

Put all your effort into improving your post as a clear, concise but also suitably detailed technical question.

Answer (score -6):

Question titles shall follow [Title Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case#Headings_and_publication_titles----) of some form, specifically capitalize all words except those 'closed class words' *e.g.*:

- "Is There a Style Guide that Provides Guidelines for Question Title and Question Content?"
- "How Should I Normalize my Data?"
- etc.

Comment: I still prefer the *Sentence case*.

Comment: when I look at the list of questions, I like it better in title case; although when looking at an individual question, I have no preference.